# Pull in JSON objects using jQuery avoiding XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to pull in data from a JSON facebook feed. I was able to do it like this:

```
$.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/jessekiro7/posts?access_token=354581914738002|SlHvFFksutZP9kcYRFobNKjg7WI&limit=1", function(data){
  $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
    $( "<a href=" + value[0].link +  " target='_blank' class='fbmsga'> <p><img src=" + value[0].picture + " /> " + value[0].message + "</p></a>" ).appendTo( "div.fbmsg" );
  });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7qu9xns2/

However, I have come to find out that this is not secure - vulnerable to XSS.

So I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/jessekiro7/posts?access_token=354581914738002|SlHvFFksutZP9kcYRFobNKjg7WI&limit=1',
}).done( function( data ){
    var a = $( '<div></div>' );
    $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        a.attr( 'class', data );
        a.text( data );

        $( 'div.fbmsg' ).append( a );
    });
});
```

The above returns "[object object]" as is. If I use dot notation, it returns nothing.

As you can see in the first option, I was able to use dot notation to access the necessary parts of the JSON array. In the second option, I need to do the same, access the "message" - however, the dot notation does not seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I make sure I do not allow XSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to be using the dot notation in the second example. You just re-access `data` over and over.

Comment: You want `value.message`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The difference is that he's using `.text()`, so it won't render HTML in the message.

Comment: You're repeatedly modifying and appending the same DIV, not creating a separate DIV for each message in `data`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the first example is susceptible to XSS. When you get data from JSON you need to set the text node, as the OP is doing in his second example, to avoid an XSS attack. The XSS vunerability comes from the way you add the data to the DOM. By using the $.text() method you are guaranteeing that no additional elements will be created if there is html markup  in the JSON data. Where as if there is html is the JSON data and you just string concatenate that into the DOM, as with the first example, those elements will be created and malicious scripts could be run on your page.

Comment: @Barmar when I add value.message, nothing displays.

Comment: @bhspencer so what could I do to avoid XSS? How would the code look with the above examples? Thanks!

Comment: @SamLuedke — Why would you expect `value.message` to work? You weren't using `value.message` in the example you said was working!

Comment: @Quentin sorry - I meant value[0].message.

Comment: @Barmar thanks missed that. I thought the question was about the AJAX request itself. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the various elements separately with javascript and append to them into the DOM. Making sure that you do not concatenate the text from the JSON response into the jQuery call that creates the element.

```
$.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/jessekiro7/posts?access_token=354581914738002|SlHvFFksutZP9kcYRFobNKjg7WI&limit=1", function(data){
    $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        var div = $("div.fbmsg");
        var a = $('<a target="_blank" class="fbmsga"></a>');
        a.attr('href', value[0].link);
        var p = $('<p></p>');
        p.text(value[0].message);
        a.append(p);
        var img = $('<img></img>');
        img.attr('src', value[0].picture);
        p.append(img);
        div.append(a);
    });
});
```

Comment: how can I add a location before the href of the link? (I changed "value[0].link" to value[0].id)

I have to change the link to the post, and to do that I need to access the ID. I have done that, but I need the first part of the link to be https://www.facebook.com/JesseKIRO7/posts/ + id +

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You create each element using the jQuery contruction function, and then build them up from lowest to highest in the hierarchy.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/jessekiro7/posts?access_token=354581914738002|SlHvFFksutZP9kcYRFobNKjg7WI&limit=1',
}).done( function( data ){
    $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
        var p = $("<p>");
        var img = $("<img>", {
            src: value.picture
        });
        p.append(img);
        var a = $("<a>", {
            href: value.link,
            target: "_blank",
            "class": "fbmsga",
            text: value.message
        }).prepend(p);
        $("div.fbmsg").append(a);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help - this gave me an error, unexpected token after: p.append($("<img>", {
            src: value.picture
        });

Comment: I was missing a parenthesis, but I've refactored it to make it more readable.